# jQuery generated select option not working on dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic, field

I have two static select fields on which jQuery script append years as options from dropdown menu and dynamic fields similar two that first two which you can add on click of 'weiter' link.

Now script for year value append works great on that first two fields which are static, but it is not appliead on that dynamically generated fields, even I'm calling them with the same class 'von_bis' as the first two.

This is because they don't exist on load of document, I suppose....

Here is current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/PnRnR/

html:

```
<span class="label-f">von:</span>
<select class="span2 von_bis" id="von" name="von">
    <option value="0">von</option>
</select>
<span class="label-f">bis:</span>
<select class="span2 von_bis" id="bis" name="bis">
    <option value="0">bis</option>
</select>

<div id="yearWrapper">
</div>

<a href="" id="btn_weitere" class="btn_weitere">weitere</a>
```

script:
    //years

```
$(function(){
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
    {
        $('.von_bis').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
    }
});
//dinamic
$(document).ready(function() {

        var MaxInputs       = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var InputsWrapper   = $("#yearWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
        var AddButton       = $("#btn_weitere"); //Add button ID

        var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
        var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

       $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
            {
                if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
                {
                    FieldCount++; //text box added increment
                    //add input box
                    $(InputsWrapper).append('\
                    <div class="form-inline f-i-f-d">\
                        <div class="form-inline f-i-f-d">\
                            <select class="span2 von_bis" id="von'+ FieldCount +'"\
                            name="von'+ FieldCount +'">\
                            <option value="0">von</option>\
                            </select>\
                            <select class="span2 von_bis" id="bis'+ FieldCount +'"\
                            name="bis'+ FieldCount +'">\
                            <option value="0">bis</option>\
                            </select>\
                        </div>\
                        <a href="#" class="removeclass">remove</a>\
                    </div>');
                    x++; //text box increment
                }
                return false;
                });

                $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                if( x > 1 ) {
                        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                        x--; //decrement textbox
                }
                return false;
                })

        });
```

How can it be applied to these dynamic fields?

Comment: Most of that is answered in the docu for [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Check out "delegated" events.

Comment: Also, since `AddButton` is a jQuery set alread, $(AddButton) doesn't really make sense. To not mix these things up I sometimes name these variables `var $addButton = $(...);` ... `$addButton.on(...);`

Comment: That isn't the problem. The issue is that the function which adds the dates was being called on load, but wasn't being called again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do it is to move the code currently being called in `$(function...)` into a function within `$(document).ready()`. After you define the function, call it so that the initial select menus will have the dates applied. Then, in the `if(x <= MaxInputs)` statement, before you call `x++;`, call the function again. You can see the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/PnRnR/1/

The issue is that you called the function only once on load, when you needed to call it everytime you added a new checkbox.